# How can I use jQuery for a growing #of selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my webpage, a user can press a button which copies the selection fields to make a sandwich to another line. I managed to change the IDs for each new selection field as so bread1, bread2, bread3 ...

In jQuery how can I refer to all of the selection fields in an event? I've tried this below, but it does not work for the newly created select fields.

```
$("select[id^='bread']").change(function({
    ...
});
```

I have also tried adding all new selects as DOM objects into an array and tried to make a jQuery object off that, but jQuery select statements don't read arrays.

Comment: Don't use ids, use a class.

Comment: The selector looks fine, you're probably looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements